# Do I need to delete the pre-install of git on mac OS before installing git via homebrew?

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I don't want to have two versions of git on my machine that might interfere with one another. I heard the best way to install git is via homebrew. However, my mac OS comes with git pre-installed (looks like an older version though) - what do you guys recommend? don't want to pollute my system or get confused later on.

Answer (score 1):

macOS does come with git preinstalled at /usr/bin/git (Check with /usr/bin/git --version to see that this is the by Apple provided version).

You can install another version of git with homebrew at /usr/local/bin and if you add the /usr/local/bin folder to the PATH string *before* /usr/bin then it will use the homebrew variant (Which is probably the more recent version). This way no confusion should arise for you I hope.

I would be careful and not delete the Apple provided git version, see also the following [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244001/how-to-uninstall-git-from-the-command-shell) in Apple SE.

Comment: Thanks Arjan, yes. I corrected for this issue.